# Convert monthly data to weekly data with pandas based on the monthly difference

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime

I am trying to convert monthly data to weekly data, however, I want continously update the weekly value based on the monthly difference, rather than just simply duplicating the value (as displayed below) or dividing it over n weeks. My original dataframe looks like the following:

```
         Date       DFF      Weeks
0  2006-01-01  4.090000 2006-01-01
1  2006-01-01  4.090000 2006-01-08
2  2006-01-01  4.090000 2006-01-15
3  2006-01-01  4.090000 2006-01-22
4  2006-01-01  4.090000 2006-01-29
5  2006-02-01  4.393333 2006-02-05
6  2006-02-01  4.393333 2006-02-12
7  2006-02-01  4.393333 2006-02-19
8  2006-02-01  4.393333 2006-02-26
9  2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-05
10 2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-12
11 2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-19
12 2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-26
```

And I want to have something that looks like this:

```
         Date       DFF      Weeks
0  2006-01-01  4.090000 2006-01-01
1  2006-01-01  4.150667 2006-01-08
2  2006-01-01  4.211333 2006-01-15
3  2006-01-01  4.272000 2006-01-22
4  2006-01-01  4.332667 2006-01-29
5  2006-02-01  4.393333 2006-02-05
6  2006-02-01  4.469167 2006-02-12
7  2006-02-01  4.545000 2006-02-19
8  2006-02-01  4.620833 2006-02-26
9  2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-05
10 2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-12
11 2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-19
12 2006-03-01  4.696667 2006-03-26
```

For example in the first case, I have computed the difference between month 1 to 2, divided this value by the number of weeks in month 1 and then continuously added (or subtracted) to the value of month 1.

I wrote the following code to create this dataframe:

```
dates = df.Date.drop_duplicates().to_list()
months = [cur_date.month for cur_date in dates]
year = 2006

for idx in range(len(weeks)):
    try:
        df_1 = df[(df.Date.dt.month == months[idx]) & (df.Date.dt.year == year)].copy()
        df_2 = df[(df.Date.dt.month == months[idx+1]) & (df.Date.dt.year == year)].copy()

        val_1 = df_1.DFF.to_list()[0]
        val_2 = df_2.DFF.to_list()[0]

        diff = val_2 - val_1
        div_diff = diff / (len(df_1))

        new_values = []

        for i in range(len(df_1)-1):
            val_1 += div_diff
            new_values.append(val_1)

        indexes = df_1.index.to_list()
        df.DFF[indexes[1]:indexes[-1]+1] = new_values

    except:
        raise IndexError("Last month of dataframe.")
```

The issues with this code are that:

1. It is clearly not efficient at all (I need to do this for approximately 12 columns over the period 2006-2022.
2. It currently only works for one year.
3. The last month produces an IndexError as obviously the loop is out of index, however this needs to work continously over the above period without stopping due to errors.

Is there a more efficient way of creating this code making better use of pandas functionality that solves the above issues?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use [`interpolate`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.interpolate.html) after masking the values on [`duplicated`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) dates, and temporarily setting the Week as index to benefit from the `time` interpolation method:

```
df['DFF2'] = (df['DFF']
    .mask(df['Date'].duplicated())
    .set_axis(pd.to_datetime(df['Weeks']))
    .interpolate(method='time')
    .to_numpy()
)
```

Output:

```
          Date       DFF       Weeks      DFF2
0   2006-01-01  4.090000  2006-01-01  4.090000
1   2006-01-01  4.090000  2006-01-08  4.150667
2   2006-01-01  4.090000  2006-01-15  4.211333
3   2006-01-01  4.090000  2006-01-22  4.272000
4   2006-01-01  4.090000  2006-01-29  4.332666
5   2006-02-01  4.393333  2006-02-05  4.393333
6   2006-02-01  4.393333  2006-02-12  4.469167
7   2006-02-01  4.393333  2006-02-19  4.545000
8   2006-02-01  4.393333  2006-02-26  4.620833
9   2006-03-01  4.696667  2006-03-05  4.696667
10  2006-03-01  4.696667  2006-03-12  4.696667
11  2006-03-01  4.696667  2006-03-19  4.696667
12  2006-03-01  4.696667  2006-03-26  4.696667
```

Comment: Amazing, works as expected. Thank you very much @mozway !